# Dynamic div displaying incorrectly

Tags: jquery, html, css, leaflet

I have a dynamic legend being added into a leaflet map.

My issue is where the `div.innerHTML +='</div>'` gets called before the if statements and for statement have finished.

I've been looking into Callbacks but I'm just really stuck after hours of looking at this, and seem to be going in circles

```
/*Legend Control */
function maplegendControl() {
  dynamicmapLegend = L.control({
    position: 'topright'
  });
  dynamicmapLegend.onAdd = function(map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend'),
      legendcolors = ["#7c7c7c", "#9d2a2a", "#26a82f"],
      legendlabels = ["Blue", "Red", "Green"];
    div.innerHTML += '<div class="legend-inner-top">' + '<div class="legend-inner-top-m" style="padding-top: 3px color: #e3e3e3;"><strong style="color: #e3e3e3">Legend</strong></div>' + '<div class="legend-inner-top-m" style="float: right;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-legend closeLegend"></button></div>' + '</div>' + '<div class="legend-inner-bottom">'
    if (map.hasLayer(jungle)) {
      // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval
      for (var i = 0; i < legendcolors.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
          '<div style="margin-top: 10px;"><i style="background:' + legendcolors[i] + '"></i>' + legendlabels[i] + "</div>";
      }
    }
    if (map.hasLayer(tropical)) {
      div.innerHTML += '<i><img src="assets/img/legend-tropical.png" alt="Tropical Icon" height="18" width="18"></i>' + 'Tropical' + "<div style='margin-top: 10px;'></div>";
    }
    if (map.hasLayer(forest)) {
      div.innerHTML += '<i><img src="assets/img/legend-forest.png" alt="Forest Icon" height="18" width="18"></i>' + 'Forest' + "<div style='margin-top: 10px;'></div>";
    }
    div.innerHTML += '</div>'
    return div;
  }
  dynamicmapLegend.addTo(map);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem here is that `.innerHTML` doesn't work the way you're expecting. It's not like `document.write()` where you can write things to the HTML page piecemeal, with the `<div>` and `</div>` and all the things in between written out separately.

This may be why it appears that the `</div>` is being added early: if you assign into `.innerHTML` and don't close your tags, the browser will do it for you. The first `.innerHTML` assignment near the top of `onAdd()` doesn't leave the tags open as `document.write()` would do, it closes them right there. That's why the other tags written below aren't getting nested inside.

If you use `.innerHTML` you should create a string with the complete DOM fragment in it, and then after that string is built, assign the entire string into `.innerHTML`.

Starting from the code you have now, a direct translation would be:

```
/*Legend Control */
function maplegendControl() {
  dynamicmapLegend = L.control({
    position: 'topright'
  });
  dynamicmapLegend.onAdd = function(map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend'),
      legendcolors = ["#7c7c7c", "#9d2a2a", "#26a82f"],
      legendlabels = ["Blue", "Red", "Green"],
      html = '';
    html += '<div class="legend-inner-top">' + '<div class="legend-inner-top-m" style="padding-top: 3px color: #e3e3e3;"><strong style="color: #e3e3e3">Legend</strong></div>' + '<div class="legend-inner-top-m" style="float: right;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-legend closeLegend"></button></div>' + '</div>' + '<div class="legend-inner-bottom">'
    if (map.hasLayer(jungle)) {
      // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval
      for (var i = 0; i < legendcolors.length; i++) {
        html +=
          '<div style="margin-top: 10px;"><i style="background:' + legendcolors[i] + '"></i>' + legendlabels[i] + "</div>";
      }
    }
    if (map.hasLayer(tropical)) {
      html += '<i><img src="assets/img/legend-tropical.png" alt="Tropical Icon" height="18" width="18"></i>' + 'Tropical' + "<div style='margin-top: 10px;'></div>";
    }
    if (map.hasLayer(forest)) {
      html += '<i><img src="assets/img/legend-forest.png" alt="Forest Icon" height="18" width="18"></i>' + 'Forest' + "<div style='margin-top: 10px;'></div>";
    }
    html += '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = html;
    return div;
  }
  dynamicmapLegend.addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: Ah got it, going at it for 10hours and needed an new perspective :), works perfectly thanks

Comment: Excellent, glad that helped! I hear you on the 10 hours. Don't tell anyone, but in my case it's sometimes been more like 20 hours!